# Fréchet distribution parameters estimation in R?

Tags: r, distribution, data-fitting, weibull

I would need to calculate the parameters of a Fréchet distribution.

I am using the packages fitdistrplus and evd of R. But I don't know
what values to initialize the parameters.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
library(evd)

#Datos
x<-c(19.1,20.2,14.3,19.0,18.8,18.5,20.0,18.6,11.4,15.6,17.4,16.2,15.7,14.3,14.9,14.0,20.2,17.4,18.6,17.0,16.0,12.2,10.8,12.4,10.2,19.8,23.4)
fit.frechet<-fitdist(x,"frechet")


fit.frechet<-fitdist(x,"frechet")
```

generating the following error

```
Error in computing default starting values.
Error in manageparam(start.arg = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,  : 
  Error in start.arg.default(obs, distname) : 
  Unknown starting values for distribution frechet. `
```

When starting the parameters:

```
fit.frechet2<-fitdist(x,"frechet", start = list(loc=0,scale=1, shape=1))
```

Output:

```
 Warning messages:
1: In fitdist(x, "frechet", start = list(loc = 0, scale = 1, shape = 1)) :
  The dfrechet function should return a vector of with NaN values when input has inconsistent parameters and not raise an error
2: In fitdist(x, "frechet", start = list(loc = 0, scale = 1, shape = 1)) :
  The pfrechet function should return a vector of with NaN values when input has inconsistent parameters and not raise an error
3: In sqrt(diag(varcovar)) : NaNs produced
4: In sqrt(1/diag(V)) : NaNs produced
5: In cov2cor(varcovar) :
  diag(.) had 0 or NA entries; non-finite result is doubtful  

Fitting of the distribution ' frechet ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
       estimate Std. Error
loc   -12128345   40.10705
scale  12128360   40.10705
shape   3493998        NaN
```

How can I estimate the parameters of the frechet in R?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try limit your values and start with some reasonable estimates

F.e.

```
fit.frechet<-fitdist(x, "frechet", method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0, 0), start = list(loc=1,scale=12, shape=4))
```

will produce couple of expected warnings, and

```
print(fit.frechet)
```

will print somewhat reasonable values

```
loc   2.146861e-07
scale 1.449643e+01
shape 4.533351e+00
```

with plot of fit vs empirical

```
plot(fit.frechet,demp=TRUE)
```

[image]

UPDATE

I would say that Frechet might not be a good fit for your data. I tried Weibull and it looks a lot better, check it yourself

```
fit.weibull<-fitdist(x, "weibull", method = "mle", lower = c(0, 0))
print(fit.weibull)
plot(fit.weibull, demp=TRUE)
```

Output is

```
shape  5.865337
scale 17.837188
```

One could note that scale parameter is kind of similar and could have been guessed just from histogram. Plot for Weibull fit, given the data it looks quite good

[image]

Comment: I have considered the Weibull distribution in my analysis, but I need to make many fittings (> 1000)  and need to systematize the definition of initial parameters for frechet distribution